# open shift war deployment error

Tags: java, apache, cloud, openshift, redhat

getting below error when deploying war to openshift using git command..i was able to deploy correctly earlier but not sure what happened and now not able to deploy and getting this error..in local i am able to run the same wat correctly.

> 

```
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSetINFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ap
ache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.114.129-8080"]
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2841 ms
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Sep 25, 2014 12:59:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/53579b125004465e18000995/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/abc.war
Sep 25, 2014 1:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 25, 2014 1:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 25, 2014 1:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/53579b125004465e18000995/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in
8,534 ms
Sep 25, 2014 1:00:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.114.129-8080"]
Sep 25, 2014 1:00:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 60436 ms
```

Comment: I had the same issue.  Logs didn’t say me nothing – no error or such. At the end I found out it was wrong address to database. I still don’t know why I hadn’t any error like “Connection failed”. Maybe here is the same case?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an exception is being thrown from your application. Is this the catalina.out log? How are you deploying the application (via IDE or?).

Comment: Has to be a more verbose log you can take a glimpse at.